# C# - Global internal const?

Tags: c#, attributes, constants, global

I'm trying to do the following:

```
[FooAttribute(Value = String.Format("{0} - {1}", myReources.BaseString, "Bar"))]
public int FooBar { get; set; }
```

The compiler complains though... so what is the correct way to do it where I have my `BaseString` in one location? My code is littered with attributes on the properties inside my library, so "global" internal const sound like the solution since I can't use resources.

Comment: And, what exactly does the compiler complain about?

Comment: Also, you can't have expressions like `String.Format` in Attributes, they have to be compile time constants. I don't know if a `const` variable counts for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have expressions like string.Format in an attribute...but the following should work:

```
public class MyResources
{
    public const string BaseString = "there";
}

[FooAttribute(Value = MyReources.BaseString + " - Bar"))]
public int FooBar { get; set; }
```

Comment: I guess this is the way... the only way to really get a compile-time constant in there...

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the String.Format and use basic string concatenation, the compiler will not complain.  Since String.Format is resolved at runtime and not compile time, you can't use it in attributes.  The compiler will recognize that both the myResources.BaseString and "Bar" are constant values so it's legal to do this.

`[FooAttribute(Value = myReources.BaseString + "Bar")]`

Comment: Actually, if what people have said is correct (that it requires a compile-time constant) then I can't use resources at all because they're exposed as properties using the defaul ResX Generator.